# Flutter - Unable to type in textformfield

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have created a form for an app and 3 text form fields inside it. I can't type in any of them. I have checked, there are no syntax errors or anything. I have run the app on both an emulator and a physical device. It still doesn't work. As soon as I click on any of the fields, the keyboard immediately goes down, even if it doesn't,I cant see what I am typing (NOT A RENDERFLEX issue)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

class AuthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthPageState createState() => _AuthPageState();
}

class _AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {
  final _Key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String name = "";
  String email = "";
  String pass = "";
  String dob;
  String country;
  String passId;
  bool passHidden = true;
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[400],
          title: Text("Personal Details"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Text(
                'All fields are mandatory and all details must be the same as your passport. Be sure to check if you are eligible on the about page',
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto-Condensed', fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
              Form(
                key: _Key,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: _controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Full Name",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Antonio"),
                          prefixIcon:
                              Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.deepOrange[400]),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0))),
                      validator: (val) {
                        if (val.isEmpty) {
                          return "Name is needed";
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          name = val;
                        });
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Email",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Antonio"),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0)),
                          prefixIcon:
                              Icon(Icons.mail, color: Colors.deepOrange[400])),
                      validator: (val) {
                        if (EmailValidator.validate(val)) {
                          return null;
                        } else {
                          return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                        }
                      },
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          email = val;
                        });
                      },
                      // onSaved: (val) {
                      //   setState(() {
                      //     email = val;
                      //   });
                      // },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      onSaved: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          pass = val;
                        });
                      },
                      validator: (val) {
                        if (val.isEmpty) {
                          return "Password can not be empty";
                        }
                        if (val.length < 6) {
                          return 'Password must be more than 6 characters';
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      obscureText: passHidden,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Password',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Antonio'),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key,
                              color: Colors.deepOrange[400]),
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(passHidden
                                ? Icons.visibility_off
                                : Icons.visibility),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                passHidden = passHidden ? false : true;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0))),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what I got on my command line

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20218): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20218): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20218): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20218): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

I searched what this means, and most ppl say it doens matter

How do I fix this ?